# MDX dynamic year in filter

Tags: mdx

I have the following simple MDX fetching quantity from my data cube:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
{  
  [Measures].[QTY]
} ON COLUMNS FROM
(
  SELECT
  (
    [DATE].[YEAR].&[2022] : null 
  ) ON COLUMNS FROM [MY_DATA_CUBE]
)
```

As you can see the lower limit range for DATE.YEAR dimension is here hard coded (2022). There's no upper limit (null) so this is like DATE.YEAR >= 2022.

I'd like to have MDX with dynamic value (current year - 2). How to do this?